# How to add a gallery script inside the infowindow Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, baguettebox

I have a script running inside the infobox called baguettebox.js

The problem is that when I click the pins an infowindow pops up and the image gallery is not arrange **but when you click again the pin** the gallery get arranged.

Here is the script and here is my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duhq62tc/).

```
function fb_gallery() {
    var gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gal-item"),
        galleryLength = gallery.length,
        displayedImages = 4;
    
    if( galleryLength > displayedImages ){
        for( var f=0; f<galleryLength; f++ ){
        if( f >= displayedImages ){
            gallery[f].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    
      var diff = galleryLength - displayedImages,
            em = document.createElement('em');
      em.innerHTML = "+" + diff;
    
      gallery[displayedImages-1].classList.add("expanded");
      gallery[displayedImages-1].children[0].appendChild(em);
    }
    
    // init lightbox plugin
    baguetteBox.run('.cc_gallery');
}



var markers = [{
    info: '<div class="cc_gallery"><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a></div>',
    lat: "37.791012",
    lng: "-122.402100"
}, {
    info: '<div class="cc_gallery"><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a></div>',
    lat: "37.765251",
    lng: "-122.435959"
}, {
    info: '<div class="cc_gallery"><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a><a href="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="gal-item"><span><img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="85" height="85" alt="" /></span></a></div>',
    lat: "37.776272",
    lng: "-122.484917"  
}];



function initializeMaps() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        //center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    const image = {
      url: "http://francistan77.com/red-pin.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(61, 75),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 75),
    };

    const image_clicked = {
      url: "http://francistan77.com/blue-ping.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(61, 75),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 75),
    };

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
        bounds.extend(pos);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            icon: image,
            map: map
        });
        
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i].info);
                fb_gallery();
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
                  marker.setIcon(image);
                })
                
                marker.setIcon(image_clicked);
                
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    
    
}

initializeMaps();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out

I just added this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'domready',function(){
    fb_gallery();
});
```

so I think the script is added to DOM and is ready for execution